# url.link error: A route named 'Default' could not be found in the route collection. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on a MVC application and trying to use the `Url.Link` function to build a working url.

Here's some relevant code:

In the **RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The route I am trying to reach in the controller (the function's name is Manage - it accepts a parameter named id that is of type guid:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("manage/{id:guid}")]
```

Call to `Url.Link()`:

```
Url.Link("Default", new { Controller = "Users", Action = "Manage", id = aggregateId });
```

I have tried naming the the attribute as such:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("manage/{id:guid}", Name="ManageUserRoute")]
```

Then calling `Url.Link()` like this:

```
url = Url.Link("ManageUserRoute", new { id = aggregateId });
```

I get the same error in the title using both methods. How do I correct this?

Comment: Assuming the action is  `ActionResult Manage(Guid id)` in the `UsersController`, you construct the link via convention-based routing like `Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Users", action = "Manage", id = aggregateId });`. *note common names for `controller` and `action`*. Your example is mixing both attribute routing and convention-based routing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is mixing both attribute routing and convention-based routing.

Assuming the action is  `ActionResult Manage(Guid id)` in the `UsersController`, you construct the link via convention-based routing like

```
Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Users", action = "Manage", id = aggregateId });
```

Note the ***common/lower case*** names for `controller` and `action` “route values” used to compose the URL

**UPDATE**

After some investigating I also notice that you failed to mention that this is for Web API not MVC. The clue was that there is no `Link` method in the MVC version of `UrlHelper`.

So more than likely you are getting that error because the default convention-based route for Web api is `DefaultAPi` not `Default`

```
// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

which is why it cannot find the `Default` route name in the route table for http route mappings. You need to check your `WebApiConfig.cs` file for the routes for your Web API.

So you probably want

```
Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Users", action = "Manage", id = aggregateId });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly a thing he tried already in code block #3?

Comment: But aren't the route values case sensitive? He also didn't show the action hence my assumption just before the code snippet.

Comment: oh, you might be right, I see what you mean now.  Can you update your answer to point out the lowercase C and A in the route a little more clearer?

Comment: I did right after the snippet *note the common name for controller and action*

Comment: Is there a MVC equivalent to what I am doing? You're right in saying this is not an API method. Thanks

Comment: I believe `Url.Action` should provide it.

Comment: UrlHelper actually doesn't have the action method - I tried using Url.Route with the same parameters as Url.Link, but I then received the same error as the original post

Answer (score 1):

If your route name is **Default**, or whatever other name, make sure you specify it in the Name property.

Example:

```
       [Route("{id:int}", Name="Default")]
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)

...
                      return CreatedAtRoute("Default",
                         new {  id = x },
                         _mapper.Map<MyModel>(talk));
```

Answer (score 0):

For MVC Use this

```
Url.Action("inspsrc")
```

Solved the same problem for me.